# Float Phonegap Activity in Android

Tags: android, cordova

I need to create a phonegap activity which only uses part of the screen for Android platform.

I tried to use dialog theme for that phonegap activity, however only a dialog frame was shown and there was no content inside.

I also tried to use transparent background color for the webview and html elements, but I got a black background.

I am using Phonegap 3.3.0.

Is there anyone can help? Thanks. **:D**

Answer (score 1):

Had developed a Plugin for Cordova Activity , do check : [Here](http://abrahamk.in/cordovaFloatingActivityPlugin/#)